# Is there a difference enrolling the developer program via macOS or iOS?

Tags: developer-program

I guess the title says it all :).

I want to enrol into the Apple Developer Program. Now I am wondering, if it would make a difference between enrolling via macOS (or better the website) or via the iOS (or iPadOS) app?

The iOS enrolment would be managed via the AppStore I guess, while the macOS would not?

Comment: Unless something has changed, you can only develop using a Mac.

Comment: That’s true, but you can enroll using the website or the iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

### No

It does not make any difference. There's only one Apple Developer Program you can enrol into.

While enrolling please make sure to correctly choose whether you want to enrol as an Individual, an Organization, or register for Apple Developer Enterprise Program.

To learn more you can refer to the following links on Apple Developer website:

- https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/
- https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: Haha! :) I got "outtimed" ;)